# What is the biggest periodic river?

Tags: rivers

What is the biggest and longest periodic river in the world ? (river that runs dry on occasion and flows during a season of heavy rain)

Comment: The question needs to be more specific. Biggest in what sense? Catchment area, bank-full cross section, maximum discharge? If the latter, maximum in the sense of which average recurrence interval? Controlled or uncontrolled rivers? The Darling used to have occasional dry seasons, but is now controlled. The Colorado wasn't seasonally dry at the Mexican border before it was dammed for water supply.

Comment: Should the word 'periodic' be modified to 'ephermeral', which seems to be the more techincal term?

Comment: Maybe Okavango river, which has a huge endorheic delta during rain season.